# share symfony2 session data

Tags: php, symfony, session

I have to share session data between a Symfony 2 application and a standalone application using Symfony/HttpFoundation component.

Both applications share the same domain, for example:

- application A (symfony2): http://example.dev
- application B (standalone, Symfony/HttpFoundation): http://example.dev/admin

Standard configuration for application A, in a controller:

```
$session = $this->get('session');
```

Application B:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
$session = new Session();
$session->start();
```

It seems that two session are independent and var_dump

```
    var_dump($session->all())
```

gives different results.

Thank you.

---

## Solution:

By default, Symfony saves session in cache folder (thank you MouradK) so it must be configured to use default php.ini handler:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/session/sessions_directory.html

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: ~
```

Comment: Default session on symfony 2 are saved in a file, if you have 2 apps differents, that should explain it.